# XPC service to support multiple protocols

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, xpc

I've got a target in my Xcode project that generate XPCService. Now I wish to implement more functions of different context, so I'd like to add them into different protocol.

I wish that the current xpc service support connections from both protocols.

the default code for single protocol support looks like this :

```
    // Create the delegate for the service.
    ServiceDelegate *delegate = [ServiceDelegate new];

    // Set up the one NSXPCListener for this service. It will handle all incoming connections.
    NSXPCListener *listener = [NSXPCListener serviceListener];
    listener.delegate = delegate;

    // Resuming the serviceListener starts this service. This method does not return.
    [listener resume];
```

whereas the `ServiceDelegate` has the following method :

`- (BOOL)listener:(NSXPCListener *)listener shouldAcceptNewConnection:(NSXPCConnection *)newConnection {`

and I set the protocol for that connection decisively without option to choose `myFirstProtocol`

`newConnection.exportedInterface = [NSXPCInterface interfaceWithProtocol:@protocol(myFirstProtocol)];`

now I have `mySecondProtocol` as well and I want to choose protocol according to connection attribute that I send on the client side .. I'm looking for some sort of identifier that help me select the right interface.

thanks !

Comment: Do you have multiple connections (and thus, exported objects)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying out setting interfaces dynamically.

So, something like:
1.let the service export a protocol that has a single method `requestInterface(kind: String)`
2. let the connecting process call `requestInterface` with a string specifying what kind of interface it wants
3. at that point change the `exportedInterface`